# Integrity error django

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite

I was using sqlite3 for my database in django project and then I decided to change it to mysql engine. I changed everything in the settings.py correctly, and in order not to lose the db I dumped my sqlite one to text and I changed every " with `, removed Commit and all things related to sqlite3. I executed the dump file on mysql and everything was added perfectly. However, when I try to add a cateogory in a table called categories.

I get this error message

> IntegrityError at /admin/red_carpet/category/
>   (1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 1")

I thought the key is duplicate wich what is the error saying. I looked at the "id" column to see it is structure I found that the id column is "NOT NULL". There was no auto increment added to that column so I added it and tried to do category from admin page I got the same error I looked again at the structure and then I added the query that the `auto_increment` shouldn't start from 0 but should start from last value which was 6. Then I added the category from the django admin again but I still get the same error, looked again at the structure and especially in the indexes part in phpmyadmin I found that line

```
Keyname Type        Cardinality  Action  Field
PRIMARY  PRIMARY       9                 id
```

For me, everything looks good and actually when I add value through django admin I get it added though I get the same error message

> IntegrityError at /admin/red_carpet/category/
>   (1062, "Duplicate entry '0' for key 1")

I really can't understand why is this problem !!!! Anyone have been thorough this before !! ??

PS: I get the same error message when I try to remove something. For example, if I am removing a cateogory I get the exat error message though when I look at the db I found that the category has been removed !!

Comment: @okm of course I did that before I post my question

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent cross-db issues would be to use fixtures, e.g. dump and load your data in (db-agnostic) json format:

see [dump data command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) and
[what is a fixture](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#what-s-a-fixture) 
from the django documentation.